# Access violation reading location 0xC0000005 C++

Tags: c++

My add function clearly has a problem as it is dereferencing first and first is pointing to nothing because of that. I just don't know how to fix it so that it isn't a null pointer.

```
    struct Node
    {
        int data;
        Node *next;
    };

    class LinkedList
    {
        Node *first;
        Node *last;
        int count;
        public:

        LinkedList()
        {
            first = NULL;
            last = NULL;
            count = 0;
        }


        void Add(int item)
        {
            if (first == NULL)
            {
                first->data = item;
                last->data = item;
                last->next = NULL;
                first->next = last;
                count = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Node *newNode = new Node;
                newNode->data = last->data;
                newNode->next = last;
                last->data = item;
                last->next = NULL;
                count ++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want `first` to be null, then point it to something.  You already know how to create a `Node` (as shown in your `else` block), so do: `first = new Node;`.

Comment: Your conditional says `if first is null, then use first`. This is incorrect. You can't use `first` if its null.

Comment: You can make it not NULL by allocating memory for it, just like you did in the else case (`Node *newNode = new Node;`).

Answer (score 6):

You have a lot of code in common between the `if` and the `else`.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first->data = item;
            last->data = item;
            last->next = NULL;
            first->next = last;
            count = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
            last->data = item;
            last->next = NULL;
            count ++;
        }
```

In the `if`, you increment `count` from `0` to `1`.  In the `else`, you *also* increment it.

`count` is **always** getting incremented.  So you don't need to type it twice.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first->data = item;
            last->data = item;
            last->next = NULL;
            first->next = last;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
            last->data = item;
            last->next = NULL;
        }
        count ++;
```

You're also setting `last->data` to `item` in both of them.

And you're setting `last->next` to `NULL` in both of them.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first->data = item;
            first->next = last;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
        }
        last->data = item;
        last->next = NULL;
        count ++;
```

You also forgot to create a `new Node` when it's the first new node.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;   // Added
            first = newNode;            // Added
            last = newNode;             // Added
            first->data = item;
            first->next = last;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
        }
        last->data = item;
        last->next = NULL;
        count ++;
```

The `first->data = item` in your `if` is redundant.  `first` is the same as `last` there, and `last->data = item` is already happening.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            first = newNode; 
            last = newNode;
            // Removed
            first->next = last;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
        }
        last->data = item;
        last->next = NULL;
        count ++;
```

And since `first` and `newNode` have **the same value** in that `if`, we can use the variable names interchangeably.

```
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node; 
            first = newNode;            // These two pointers are equal!
            last = newNode;
            newNode->next = last;       // (same pointer)
        }
        else
        {
            Node *newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = last->data;
            newNode->next = last;
        }
        last->data = item;
        last->next = NULL;
        count ++;
```

Now, **almost everything** in your `else` is also in your `if`.  It can **all** be moved out.

```
        Node *newNode = new Node; 
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            newNode->data = last->data;
        }
        newNode->next = last;
        last->data = item;
        last->next = NULL;
        count ++;
```

That code should be more understandable now, too.  The lesson: [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).  :)

Comment: Excellent post with plenty of detail and good explanations so the OP can follow along. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
if (first == NULL)
{
    /* if first is NULL dereference it. Hooray! */
    first->data = item;
    ...
```

Comment: I think the OP might already know that ("it is dereferencing first and first is pointing to nothing") but doesn't understand how to *fix* it.

Comment: What about just simply `first = new Node;`?

Comment: @BdkFivehunna you're going to need a `new Node` regardless of whether it's NULL or not.

Comment: @jamesdlin considering that the `else` part of the loop allocates a new node, that seems unlikely. But you never know.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Actually the OP replied to this answer and confirmed what I said, but for some reason deleted the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)

There are few details, to start with when `first == NULL` you need to create first, insert it into linked list and hook it up, see linked article for some algorithms.

I would say the simplest is single linked list with a header node (instead of `first *`) which could point to itself, but there are many ways to implement linked list and it depends on what you choose how to hook up the elements.

It depends on what you are after but if you just need something working then you could pick up from [boost intrusive circular slist algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/intrusive/node_algorithms.html) where you just define your own struct with data and next pointer, tell it how to access next and use provided algorithms to do all the work (link and unlink nodes).